# Spring MVC Map object from multiple tables based on id

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have 2 models:

Contract Header

```
public class ContractHeader {

@Id
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "contractHeader")
private List<ContractEntitlement> contractEntitlements;
```

ContractEntitlement

```
public class ContractEntitlement {

@Id
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private ContractHeader contractHeader; 

@Column(name = "ch_id")
private int chId;
```

1 contract (id) can have multiple entitlement (ch_id) so when I create a form my controller is:

```
ContractHeader ch = new ContractHeader();
ch.setContractEntitlements(new AutoPopulatingList<ContractEntitlement>(ContractEntitlement.class));

model.addAttribute("ch", ch);
```

this works perfectly and was able to save the data for both tables but now my problem is retrieving them:

View Controller:

```
model.addAttribute("contractHeader", new ContractHeader());
model.addAttribute("ch", this.contractHeaderService.listContractHeaders());

model.addAttribute("contractEntitlement", new ContractEntitlement());
model.addAttribute("ce", this.contractEntitlementService.listContractEntitlements());
```

View jsp

```
<c:forEach items="${ch}" var="contractHeader">
    ... Elements to show each data
    <c:forEach items="${ce}" var="contractEntitlement">
        <c:if test="${contractHeader.id ==  contractEntitlement.chId}" >
        ... Elements to show each data
```

I generate 2 objects and compare the id in the view jsp.

DAO ContractHeader

```
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    List<ContractHeader> contractHeaderList = session.createQuery("from ContractHeader").list();
```

DAO ContractEntitlement

```
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    List<ContractEntitlement> contractEntitlementList = session.createQuery("from ContractEntitlement").list();
```

Is there a better or shall I say a proper way to get the data the same as when I created them by using one model (ContractHeader)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, as it seems you are trying to hierarchically present data in loops, I would go for query which retrieves `ContractHeader` entities with fetched `ContractEntitlements` entites:

```
Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
List<ContractHeader> contractHeaderList = session.createQuery(
   "select ch from ContractHeader ch inner join fetch ch.contractEntitlements")
   .list();
```

Then change the page part to:

```
<c:forEach items="${ch}" var="contractHeader">
    ... Elements to show each data
    <c:forEach items="${ch.contractEntitlements}" var="contractEntitlement">
        ... Elements to show each data
```

Now, i think you would not need to use that extra test in the nested loop.